# Ставится ли запятая в предложении "Всё что не утонет будет сожжено"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

Ставится ли запятая в предложении? и где именно?

Comment: На мой взгляд, "всё, что не утонет, будет сожжено" https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91+%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%22

Comment: @prostorech чтобы дать ответ, пожалуйста, используйте подходящую для этого форму ответа.

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1):

Придаточное предложение внутри главного.

Главное: "Всё будет сожжено".

Придаточное: "Что не утонет".

Всё, что не утонет, будет сожжено.

Comment: Что значит "новый участник"? Теперь насовсем?

Answer (score 1):

Это сложноподчиненное предложение, в котором придаточное предложение *что не утонет* стоит в середине главного, поэтому отделяется от него запятыми (*что* — союзное слово).

[Сложноподчинённые предложения](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/735-21_obschaya_harakteristika_slozhnopodchinennyh_predlozhenii.html)

**Всё, что не утонет, будет сожжено.**